# partially updating wcf service reference

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, service-reference

I have a wcf service where I do some business specific processes. I use this service from a mvc3 web application. since I'm still in development process I change my web service a lot by adding new methods or changing the signatures of methods. then I need to update my service reference on web application, but as far as I understand when I do that the reference class gets created from the scratch. problem here, that I want to add some logic into service reference. but in this case each time I update the service reference, additional parts that I've added gets lost, and I need to manually copy paste and adjust my code. What is the right way of going around this issue?

Comment: Use partial classes - put the code you want to keep (your custom code) in them.  When you update your reference you'll still have your custom code.

Comment: Absolutely, never, never, never manually update generated code. All changes will be lost at the first regen. Proxy classes should be logic- less.

Comment: right after posting this question I actually figured that solution out :) but didn't answered since I might still get good answers. Thanks.

Comment: personally I try to sidestep the problem entirely. Generate Service Reference simply creates a set of classes that map on to the classes on the server. If you split out those classes and interfaces into a "contracts" assembly, both your server side code and your client side code can reference the same source. This can generally ease deployment issues by a lot. The only downside is that this only works if your team is working on the source code of both the client and the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a partial class, or deriving a class from the service reference and adding all the custom logic in that class will provide the ability to updating the service reference while keeping the custom code. This approach looks very neat to me. Thanks for the ideas.